# Dynamic Propery Bindning-Parent child relationship between components in angular2

Tags: angular

```
   **how can we dynamically bind the property of child component to the html page of parent component in angular2?**

  **Component property binding
```

Parent component should be able to access the child component** property in html page dynamically
    Parentcomponent.ts
        parentcomponent{
    ngOnInit(){

```
    call child component method
   } }
**Here the value must be binded**
    parentcomponent.html
    "here how to bind items of childcomponent through parentcomponent "
    ex: i want the value like {{items.name}}
    and it has to change dynamically when value in childcomponent changes
    **This is child component whixh will get the value of the** item.name  from service and bind it to the html of parent component
    childcomponent.ts
    ChildComponent{
    items:any;(Item is json object with properties item id,item name etc)
    ngOnInit(){
    this.items=Itemsservice.getItems();
    }
    }
     **This is the service method.**
    itemservice.ts
    @Injectable()
    export class ItemService{
    getItems(){
    return items;
    }
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried, and post your code with your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html for Angular basics.